# c# selenium testing category

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium

My question is more theoretical rather than code related. I am implementing a test through Selenium and my approach is to test the visual parts of my application(for ex. if all pages are visible, or if a specific element is placed in a page etc).

I am not sure in which category this test belong. In my mind it is not Unit Test because does not exam code behaviour. Neither Integration Test. I wonder if I can call this test Acceptance Test or User Acceptance Test.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not really a good fit for SO. I would recommend posting on https://sqa.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: In short this seems to be from the `User Acceptance Test` category.